# Equation for Logistic regression while using One Hot Encoding

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, logistic-regression

When the features are numeric, like these:

[image]

The feature matrix X in the hypothesis `sigmoid(transpose(theta).X))` will be:

[image]

However, when we have 1 more feature here - color, which can be red or blue or green, on doing **One Hot Encoding** each will be a vector like: `[1 0 0]` `[0 1 0]` and `[0 0 1]`.

I'm unable to figure out how to merge these **One Hot Encoding** vectors to already existing feature matrix and then use it in the equation for hypothesis

Comment: If I am not mistaken this is dead simple. You just add three more features, named `red`, `blue` and `green` to your feature matrix. Can you specify your problem a little bit?

Comment: I had guessed that, but am sure whether this is most appropriate way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should remove all not encoded categorical features from dataset, encode them and add their encoded values from one hot encoding, also you have to add corresponding weights into theta of course. Then you can fit your new model on this new dataset

Comment: One more important thing missing is to never leave unpreprocessed data here. If you add one-hot-encoding features, then features like "square size" which are orders of magnitude bigger will heavily bias your model. remember about standarization.

Comment: @lejlot Also, if I feel categorical feature A is a lot more important that categorical feature B, does it make sense to have B as [0 1 0 ..... 0] and A as [0 0 8 0 ....0] for a particular value of A and B ?

Comment: And how would you decide how "much" is "much"? Weighting features by hand is rarely a good idea, as it requires extremely good knowledge of both - the problem, and model used later on (as you must understand how models treat "multiplying"). So in general - it is better to standarize and leave it to ML

Comment: @lejlot Okay. I'm new to Machine Learning. By standardization you mean always have the feature vector like [0 1 0..0] or a particular  standardization method which can be applied to Logistic Regression ?

Comment: @SaurabhVerma, By standartization he means scaling of features. Look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling